# Using Windows PowerShell to batch remove "[" character from filenames

Tags: powershell, text, replace

Trying to use PowerShell to remove an odd character, but it keeps breaking on `[`:

Filename is `test [t].txt`

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "[","_" }
```

Results in:

```
PS D:\test> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "[","_" }
Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed.
Invalid regular expression pattern: [.
At line:1 char:27
+ Dir | Rename-Item -NewName <<<<  { $_.Name -replace "[","_" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (test [t].txt:PSObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I've tried a few common ways to escape the character `\[`, `'['`, ... and nada.

Thoughts and ideas?

PS: Trying the `Replace()` method with `\[` escape:

```
PS D:\test> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName{ $_.Name.Replace("\[","_")}
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\
FileSystem::D:\test\test [t].txt' does not exist.
At line:1 char:18
+ Dir | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName{ $_.Name.Replace("\[","_")}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

PPS: The file DOES exist:

```
PS D:\test> dir
    Directory: D:\test
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         1/27/2018   4:08 PM        448 rb.bat
-a---         1/27/2018   3:04 PM          4 test [t].txt
```

The appending of the PS header to the path by something inside PS when it sees a `[` in the file name is the problem.  If I replace the `[` (bracket) with a `(` (paren) everything works as expected.

Comment: `-replace` uses regex.  Escape your brace: `'\['`

Comment: Furthermore, I'd avoid using regex if you don't *need* it.  Alternative: `$_.Name.Replace('[','_')`

Comment: Still hangs up on the [ in the expression - or if it gets by that then can't find the original file;

Comment: PS D:\test> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName{ $_.Name.Replace('[','_')}
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\test\test [t].txt' does not exist
.
At line:1 char:18
+ Dir | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName{ $_.Name.Replace('[','_')}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

PS D:\test>

Comment: **`BECAUSE D:\test\test [t].txt DOES NOT EXIST.`** Read your error messages.

Comment: It most certainly DOES exist... and that's the issue; when rename tries, the bracket in the filename doesn't get through powershell's rename function.  My original post shows the example where the passed expression IS the file I am trying to rename.

Comment: What's really odd is PS is finding the only file in the folder, processing it and when trying to rename it can no longer find it.  A post elsewhere talks of script evaluation timing being problematic; I suspect that's at the root of this issue. But my attempts to use   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion have also came up empty.

Comment: By the way - its really easy to set up; create a folder '\test' - add a test file 'test [t].txt' and then run PS - nav to '\test' and try the command.

Comment: You MUST escape the square bracket when using the `-replace` ***operator*** (`$_.Name -replace '\[', '_'`). You MUST NOT escape the square bracket when using the `Replace()` ***method*** (`$_.Name.Replace('[', '_')`).

Comment: When properly 'escaped' - still getting the file not found since PS is adding the PS provider header internally ...

Comment: Worked just fine when I tested. What is your PowerShell version? Is D: a local drive or a network drive? Is the behavior the same whan you start PowerShell with `-NoProfile`?

Comment: Powershell v1.0 -- default that was included with Windows 7 Pro.  This might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The escape charachter is a backslash. So your regex pattern should look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\[|\]','_'}
```

This will replace the opening square bracket and the closing square bracket.

Comment: Doesn't work ...PS D:\test> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[|\]','_' }
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\test\test [t].txt' does not exist
.
At line:1 char:18
+ Dir | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[|\]','_' }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

PS D:\test>

Comment: You completely ignored his answer @GWild

Comment: I completed the code in my answer. It works in my environment

Comment: Your resulting file names could look even a little better when you change your regex / replace pattern to this:  `'(\[|\]|\s)+','_'`

Comment: Could you please at least once try the code I provided in my answer exactly the way I provided it?

Comment: Olaf - doesn't work in my environment.  PS barfs when it inserts the PS path descriptor when it hits the bracket.  The get-child method was my first attempt; and the dir | method my second attempt because it got farther along. Both barf on [ (even backslash[)

Comment: PS D:\test> dir
    Directory: D:\test
-a---         1/27/2018   3:04 PM          4 test [a].txt
PS D:\test> Get-ChildItem |
>>     Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\[|\]','_'}
>>
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\test\test [a].txt' does not exist
.

Comment: note the escape \ is in the code ... but doesn't show in the comment I pasted, and the file test [a].txt exists.

Comment: I solved my problem dir dumping a bare directory listing into a text file, running it through Excel to create a massive 10000 line batch file using rename to remove the offending brackets... nothing like blunt force.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see that you resolved your situation with brute force. This code appears to produce the filename you desire.

```
PS C:\src\t\renfunc> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: C:\src\t\renfunc

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-09-11     08:51              7 test [2].txt

PS C:\src\t\renfunc> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $_.Name -replace '\[|\]','_' }
test _2_.txt
```